# Broken behavior in PhoneGap and jQueryMobile with links to other jQuery Mobile Pages

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

I created an MVC3 application using jQuery Mobile which has a view with multiple jQuery mobile pages nested in a list like the following.

Main Page

```
<div data-role="page" id="main">
  <ul data-role="listview" id="main" data-divider-theme="a">
    <li>
      <a href="#page1">Page 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#page2">Page 2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Other Pages

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
  ....
</div>
```

I also created a PhoneGapp application that offers some offline content which has a simple button menu which one directs to my externally hosted MVC site.

```
 <div data-role="page" id="mainMenu">
   <div data-role="content">
     <ul class="buttonMenu">
       <li>
          <a href="http://www.thisismymvcsite.com" data-role="button">
            <img src="mvcsite.png" alt="MVC Site" />
            <span>MVC Site</span> </a></li>
     </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

Now since I am using an External Host I added the domain to the PhoneGap.plist file, like `*.thisismymvcsite.*` to enable wild cards for sub domains.

**The Problem**

When I load up the PhoneGap application everything behaves correctly, I can even navigate to my external site and PhoneGap loads up the content within the application window.  The issue I am running into, is when i click on my `<a href="#page1">Page 1</a>` the transition to the other page occurs in PhoneGap BUT also spawns a window into Safari like I am navigating to an external host that is not configured.  If I go back to the application I see the correct jQuery Mobile page loaded up and if I try to go back to the `#mainPage` the same thing happens again.

I worked around this issue by altering the AppDelegate file in XCode to detect the `#`

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSString *absoluteUrl = [[request URL]absoluteString];

    NSRange range = [absoluteUrl rangeOfString:@"#" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
    if( range.location != NSNotFound ) {
        return YES;
    }

    return [super webView:theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:request navigationType:navigationType];
}
```

**The Question**
My hack job works, however there must be something I am missing, is there anything I am doing wrong which is causing this strange behavior?

*Note: I am using the latest PhoneGap 1.1 and jQuery Mobile 1 RC2*